# TypeError: response[idx] is undefined in ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have implemented this code from a source. But when i tried with firebug, it catched this error: TypeError: response[idx] is undefined. I tried to look for similiar topics here But none of them can help me to solve this issue. So I hope experienced user to look through these line of code to find out what the issue is.

The author of this source has not replied my question. So I don't know where to seek for the answer to this.

**Purpose of this:** 
This uses json reponse upon ajax success to render list of district options. That is how I understood, but technically, I don't know why this error occurs? Maybe the author missed or left out something by mistake?

**Here is my ajax function:**

```
function sortSubcat(str)
{
if (str=="")
{
document.getElementById("subcat").innerHTML="";
return;
} 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
 xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        var response = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        var selectElement = document.getElementById('subcat');
        for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++)
        {
            var idx = i+1;
            selectElement.options[idx] = new Option(response[idx].value, response[idx].name, false, false);
        }   
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","/member/sortsubcat.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

**Here is the php file:**

```
<?php
require_once("../configs/dbconnect.php");
if (!empty($_GET['q'])){
$q = basename($_GET['q']);
$sql="SELECT * FROM subcat WHERE maincat=:q";
$result = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result->bindParam(':q', $q);
$result->execute();
$returned_string = '[';
foreach($result as $row)
{
    //echo "<option value='$row[name]'>$row[name]</option>";
     $returned_string .= '{"name" : "'. $row['name']. '", "value" : "'. $row['name']. '"},';
}
$returned_string = substr($returned_string, 0, -1); //remove trailing ','
$returned_string .= ']';
header("Content-type: application/json");
echo $returned_string;
exit;
}
else{
echo "<option value=''>Please select a district</option>";
}
$conn=null;
?>
```

**Here is the response from json:**

```
[{"name" : "District A", "value" : "District A"},{"name" : "District B", "value" : "District B"}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're accessing past the end of the array in this loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++)
{
    var idx = i+1;
    selectElement.options[idx] = new Option(response[idx].value, response[idx].name, false, false);
}
```

`i` has the correct index values for the loop, which start at `0` and go through `length - 1`. You don't want `idx` at all (except that I assume you're skipping the first `selectElement` option on purpose; it's "blank" or similar), so:

```
for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++)
{
    //                    vvv--- skip the first select option, so +1 here
    selectElement.options[i+1] = new Option(response[i].value, response[i].name, false, false);
    // But use i for accessing the array ------------^------------------^
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with this code:

```
for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++)
        {
            var idx = i+1;
            selectElement.options[idx] = new Option(response[idx].value, response[idx].name, false, false);
        }
```

You've only two items in the response array. but inside the for loop, you have

```
        var idx = i+1;
```

So when i = 1; idx will be 2;

But in index 2 there is no data available in the response. that's why its' giving you error. As you re trying to access value property of undefined.

You've to remove that `idx = i+1` and refer to i directly.